# How to configure the dependabot.yml for updating whenever a new python patch version for alpine is available on docker hub?

Tags: docker, dependabot

I'm using Docker for codebase and dependabot on GitHub.

### What I want

Whenever there's a new patch version for python or new minor version of alpine for the python-alpine image on docker hub see https://hub.docker.com/_/python, I want dependabot to create a new PR for it.

### What I tried

This is my dependabot.yml

```
version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: "docker" # See documentation for possible values
    directory: "/compose/local/django" # Location of package manifests
    schedule:
      interval: "monthly"
```

These are the locations of my Dockerfile.

1. for dev: /compose/local/django
2. for production: /compose/production/platform/doap

My Dockerfile at both locations start like this:

```
FROM python:3.8.7-alpine3.12

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk update \
```

I don't think it works. I don't see any PR as the latest is `python:3.8.8-alpine3.12`. How do I change my dependabot.yml?

Comment: Your config looks good to me. Maybe this could help?

https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/supply-chain-security/troubleshooting-dependabot-errors#investigating-errors-with-dependabot-version-updates

FWIW, you can see the files detected by Dependabot under "Insights / Dependency Graph / Dependabot".

Comment: FWIW your config works for me, I automatically got a PR opened by dependabot to update to python `3.9.5-alpine3.12`. Perhaps there is an issue with the path? I used `/` and put a Dockerfile in the root of the repo, and set interval to daily.